# Exclude object if one of the has_many related entities has the attribute with value x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I came across about the problem excluding data, if the attribute x of one of the associated data has the value 'a'.

Example:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order

  validate_presence_of :status
end
```

The query should return all Orders that **don't** have an Item with **status = 'paid'** (status != 'paid').

Because of the 1:n association an Order can have many Items. And one of the Itmes can have the status = 'paid'. These Orders must be excluded from the result of my query even if the order has other items with status different from 'paid'.

How would I solve this problem:

```
paid_items = Items.where(status: 'paid').pluck(:order_id)
orders_wo_paid = Order.where('id NOT IN (?)', paid_items)
```

Is there an ActiveRecord solution, that solves this problem in one query.
Or are there other ways to solve this question?

I 'm not looking for ruby solution such as:

```
Order.select do |order|
  !order.items.pluck(:status).include?('paid')         
end
```

thx for ideas and inspirations.

Comment: You could solve it with a nested sql query but i don't think it would be significantly more efficient than your own solution, and it would certainly be less readable.  I would personally go with what you've got there.

Comment: Or using a left join + grouping + counting, but left joins are not so straightforward to use with ActiveRecord, and it would be as well harder to read. Btw I think it is a typo, but what you pluck from `Items` should be `order_id` and not `id`

Comment: @Fer: can you make an example of left join + grouping + counting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you are interested in is the following, but creating with activerecord will be hard/no very readable:

```
SELECT 
  orders.*
FROM 
  orders
LEFT JOIN 
  order_items ON orders.id = order_items.order_id
GROUP BY
  order_items.order_id
HAVING 
  COUNT(DISTINCT order_items.id) = COUNT(DISTINCT order_items.status <> 'paid')
```

Sorry for the sql indentation, I have no idea which are the conventions for it.

A way (not the best one at all) to it with rails (unfortunately writing sql for the most important parts) would be the following:

```
Order.group(:order_id).joins("LEFT JOIN order_items ON orders.id = order_items.order_id")
     .having("COUNT(DISTINCT order_items.id) = COUNT(DISTINCT order_items.status <> 'paid')")
```

Of course you can play with AREL to get rid of the hard coded sql, but in my opinion it will not be easier to read.

You can have an example of creating lefts joins in this gist: https://gist.github.com/mildmojo/3724189

Comment: To correct the quer it should be items.status != 'paid'. So you will get the orders without any paid items.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
Order.where('orders.id NOT IN (?)', Item.where(status: 'paid').select(:order_id))
```

If you're using Rails 4.x then:

```
Order.where.not(id: Item.where(status: 'paid').select(:order_id))
```

Comment: UUps... It doesn't work. orders that have items.status 'paid' and other items with status != 'paid' will be in the result. thx

Comment: @nabinabou: Aahh, I see what you are trying to say. Please see the update.

Comment: Now, your query is correct, related to the question. But this solution is the same as mentioned in the question. It is not a new way to solve it. Still using two queries.